# arcGIS for android how to draw a crooked line?

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

My project meets a need to draw a curved path on the ArcGIS map But I used a lot of ways do not know how to draw a curved line in the code Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As I am understanding the requirement you want to add a curved line on the map using ***ArcGIS android sdk***.

First of all you you will be needed set of co-ordinates which you will be using to draw the line on the map.

Polylines can be added to a graphics layer and displayed using a SimpleLineSymbol. This symbol allows you to display the graphic using one of a finite list of symbol types (dash, dash dot, dash dot dot, dot, null, or solid). You can further define the symbol by specifying a width and a color.

Below are some samples of line symbols-

[image]

Once you have decided the line symbol styling use below code to add the line on the map.

```
// create a line symbol (green, 3 thick and a dash style)
SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.GREEN, 3, SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE.DASH);

// create the line geometry
Polyline lineGeometry = new Polyline();
lineGeometry.startPath(-302557, 7570663);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-302959, 7570868);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-303042, 7571220);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-302700, 7571803);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-304043, 7576654);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-300544, 7585289);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-294365, 7592435);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-290122, 7594445);
lineGeometry.lineTo(-285283, 7595488);

// create the graphic using the geometry and the symbol
Graphic lineGraphic = new Graphic(lineGeometry, lineSymbol);

// add the graphic to the graphics layer
graphicsLayer.addGraphic(lineGraphic);
```

> **Output of above code**

[image]

For more details your can refer [ArcGIS android sdk...](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/add-graphics-and-text-to-graphic-overlays.htm)

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you!